Hyperpyrexia definitions etiology and treatment?
Hyperpyrexia, Hyperthermia, Fever are terms that are used interchangably throughout literature. Completely different etiologies like intoxication, infection and hemorrhage are all labelled with those same terms.
I challenge the view that a fever can even get too high and would like to be provided with data that suggests otherwise. (please be aware that the literature often states, that very high fever (with an arbitrary value of around 40 °C) self evidently needs to be lowered. This seems to be stated as common knowledge. The cited sources for this statement however never corroborate this claim, as hyperthermia or non infectious causes are not differentiated. This is the case for every single publication I came across)
Lets define a fever:
the common view is that fever is an evolutionary highly conserved and therefore most likely beneficial physiological change in temperature homeostasis, implying that this is an actively regulated healthy response in an equilibrium between raising and lowering bodytemperature, thats been caused by pyrogens.
What concept is not part of this definition: Intoxication and Hyperthermia due to external heating and brain damage.
Can fever reach dangerous temperatures?
If we accept the given definition, it is excluded already semantically that it can. As the rise into dangerous temperature levels does imply decompensation of this homeostatic equilibrium, which can not be considered a healthy physiological response anymore but rather a pathological one, a system failure.
e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK562334/
differentiates between fever and hyperpyrexia but uses hyperpyrexia and hyperthermia synonymously.
"it is essential to understand that the definition of fever is not the same as that of hyperthermia (hyperpyrexia)."
I think this is an important differentiation because it has implications for therapeutic strategies.
When we analyze the literature we see unanimously that treating fever does not result in better outcomes.
e.g. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35820685/
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC4056101/#sec17
It also is clear that high infectious fever is inversely linked with mortality and that the dangerous 41.5 degrees are only reached in a very small fraction of patients.
If we look at the case studies of covid induced hyperpyrexia patients who died of presumably brain injury, should this really be referred to as a death due to fever?
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC7300797/
There is solely a correlation between extremely high body temperature and mortality, which might just be a reflection for the severity of the underlying cause and the switch into system failure.
How certain can we even be that fever can get too high in the sense that our bodies overreact? Isn´t it rather a failure of the system, which should not be considered a fever anymore and in which case antipyretics won´t even work?
In short:
Do you think hyperpyrexia should be considered a high fever? Is it physiological or pathological, rather an overreaction or system failure? Does it still respond to antipyretics? Do you see the mixed usage of those terms problematic? (considering fever phobia, possible mistreatment of beneficial fever, scared parents etc.)
To provide an analogy of how fever is treated:
People with diabetic acidosis hyperventilate. Since those people die if left untreated. We therefore must stop hyperventilation also during physical activity because breathing frequency might rise until death occurs. Absurd.
I am apologizing in advance as this question regularly triggers people.
Any recommendations for a discussion forum for questions like that?

I can't imagine how or why this would trigger anyone. Maybe I don't know what you mean by "trigger."

haha right? people often get very offended when someone makes outrageous claims like fever does not get too high, because it challenges common narratives.

Similarly, nothing triggering in this - except the word triggering, that annoys me.

Welcome to Medical Sciences.SE. You're going to have to go a lot further than this to offend anyone here. You can ask absolutely insane things and the worst that will get you is downvotes as long as it meets site requirements. This question does, so sorry, no triggering today.

@CareyGregory - This is a user who is upset that his post on Biology.SE (about inflammation, but fever was for some reason included) was deleted by a mod, probably for giving medical advice (something I pointed out in comments.) He just has an axe to grind. You can see more over on Bio.SE if you're interested.

Hyperthermia and hyperpyrexia aren't actually interchangeable, at least I've not seen it in the medical literature. Maybe you could give us concrete examples of it? (Your assertion that hyperpyrexia is not the same as a high fever was corrected there, and I gave you a link to a paper about infection and hyperpyrexia in children. What are you trying to prove here? That "high fever" and hyperpyrexia are two completely different things?)

@Lukas4235 - I'm not offended by outrageous claims per se. I admit I don't like groundless medical claims, like that hyperpyrexia is by necessity a distinctly different entity (and non-physiological) from fever. As I stated before, I don't mind when people give medical advice; it's when they give bad medical advice that I object (like that fever and inflammation should not be treated, as they are adaptive.)

So your purpose here is to make what you think are outrageous claims to see if you can "trigger" people? Your answer to that question will determine your future here, so answer carefully.

@CareyGregory: No I don´t wanna provoke. I wanna know the truth. I just experienced, not only with anongoodnurse but many others, that I am encountered with assertions of ignorance and incompetence, because I question some medication prescribals. I admitt that this time I may have formulated it too confident, the reason being is because I can not find contradicting literature and I am not provided with such.
ad Hyperthermia and Hyperpyrexia synonym use I already cited ncbi.gov "it is essential to understand that the definition of fever is not the same as that of hyperthermia (hyperpyrexia)."

I haven't seen anyone accuse you of ignorance or incompetence, and certainly not "many others." If you feel you've encountered that on another site, then flag the comments and the mods on that site will address the problem. My only concerns are this site and whether your questions are sincere and not a troll.
